# Origin of gen./abl. "pitur" genitive of "pitā́" ("father") in Sanskrit

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, sanskrit, declension

How did the Sanskrit gen./abl. singular of *pitr-/pitā́* ("father") came to be *pitur* (and the genitive of the entire noun class as well, of course)? The evolution of all other forms (even *pitā́*, which seems to be a regular result of *pitā́r* < *pitár-s*) seems to be fairly transparent but this one has always eluded me...

AFAIK, the source should be *ph₂tr-és* so I would expect it to yield something like *pitr-ás*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic explanation is that *ṛš becomes ur in Old Indian. The ending of the gen. sing. of Indo-Iranian -r stems is sometimes *-as and sometimes *-s. pitur is like hotur (Avestan zaotarš, with full-grade stem).

Comment: Interesting - isn't *_ph₂tr-_ hysterokinetic declension with accent typically on the ending? So I find it surprising that this would get reduced to *_ph₂tŕ-s/pitŕš_...

Comment: Is it more surprising than acc. pl. pitṝn?

Comment: Actually yes. The whole r-stem plural paradigm seems to mirror semi-vowel declensions (i-/u-stems - which does not seem that strange since in sanskrit, [i]&[u] are not difficult to reinterpret as syllabic /j/&/w/ - atypical as it may be), so while it is irregular with regards to the original PIE reconstruct, it sounds like a direct analogy to _agnī́n/śátrūn_. I see no such analogy for the gen./abl. singular.

Comment: Maybe I am derailing it a little bit - _-ṛš > -ur_ by itself does not seem like implausible at all, so do we have some further evidence that genitive of r-stems in Indian evolve from _C-r-ás_ to _C-ŕš_? I take your Avestan example as and indication that in closely related Aryan languages this is the case.

Comment: If you treat these words as vowel stems (as indeed the Indian grammarians do) then it makes sense that the gen. sing. is *pitṛ-s (> *pitṛš > pitur), not *pitr-as.

Comment: Fair enough - in that case I would expext the stem be guna form (as in _agneh/śatroh_), i.e. _pitár-š_, which should yield a form identical to nominative, but I can live with this explanation. Perhaps you should update your answer with this?

Comment: Interesting, when doing some further research I got to the Wikipedia article on older, Vedic declensions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_of_the_Vedic_language#.E1.B9.9B_and_.E1.B9.9D-stems) and actually it lists both _pitur_ **and** _pitras_ as possible gen./abl. singular so there was probably some oscillation. I wonder why it is the less transparent form that prevailed but I guess that is why one either loves sanskrit or... does not learn sanskrit at all.

Comment: Like everything on Wikipedia, this article is riddled with errors. E.g. nom. sing. is pitā, not “pita”.

Comment: Please correct it then!